# iOS: Can I get the complete CrashReport form Crashlytics directly on the affected device?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Crashlytics is remote-reporting crashes! That's perfekt!
But I'd also like a crash-report to be written to a logfile on the users device.

I saw that I can set myself as delegate on Crashlytics and I even get a `CLSReport` via the delegate method, but it doesn't seem to have any stack-trace or crash-reason whatsoever ?!?

Am I missing something or is this just not possible with Crashlytics for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Currently it's not possible to get the report. We use a custom format that reduces the size of the reports as much as possible, but has the down-side of not being an externally accessible file.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer! Do you think you will expose the report in `CLSReport ` any time soon?

Comment: Anytime @Georg and it's not on our immediate roadmap. Just for my own curiosity, what would you be looking to do with that file? Do additional external analysis or correlate with other sources?

Comment: Hi Mike,
no... not that sophisticated :D It's just that a user reported a crash that I can't find on Fabric... It's just not there... But in my app I do a lot of logging and theres a hidden gesture that allows the user to send me those logs. If they would contain crash-information it would be handy for users to report something like that...